# "Sweep failed" message when sweeping a paper wallet into a Bitcoin.com wallet

Tags: wallet, paper-wallet

I have a bunch of coin in BTC cold storage (paper wallets).  And for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to sweep them out of there.

The best attempt I've had so far was to download the Bitcoin.com app to my phone.  There in the settings it allows you to sweep a wallet.

In both cases, I put in the private key, and it shows me how much is in the wallet.  So it was able to unlock it.  But when I "slide to sweep", I get a simple toast message "Sweep Failed".  And nothing else.  No help.  No other information.  No indication as to what the problem is.  And doing a Google search on this has yielded exactly zero help.

So if anyone has any ideas, like something better, I'm all ears (eyes).

Comment: I edited the question to remove the digression because of https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1005/13866. If you disagree with the edits, click the "edited..." link and choose "rollback"

Comment: Well, okay.  But it would have been way better if you were to offer some help with the problem.  :)

Comment: I agree it would have been, but I don't use the Bitcoin.com wallet/account so don't know that message from that wallet. I figured I should make the change in order to prevent your question being closed as off topic - that way it is more likely to get an actual answer.